# Java create a dynamic ObservableList

Tags: java, dynamic, runtime, observablelist

is it possible to create a dynamic ObservableList with relative StringProperty?

For example, using the code below, how is it possible to recreate it dynamically and add new StringProperty if necessary?

```
private final ObservableList<Record> recordList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public static class Record {

    private static int trackId;
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty id;
    private final SimpleStringProperty name;
    private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;
    private final SimpleStringProperty email;

    private Record(String name, String lastName, String email) {

        this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(trackId);
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
        this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        trackId++;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id.get();
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email.get();
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email.set(email);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't add fields to class even if will use Reflection. Maybe is better to change architecture? Let's see next class:

```
class Property <T> {
    private final T propertyValue;
    private final String propertyName;

    public Property (String name, T value) {
        this.propertyName = name;
        this.propertyValue = value;
    }

    public T getValue(){
        return propertyValue;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return propertyName;
    }
}
```

This class helps you to create new property and store it. Now, you can create List of properties and store it in class Record. And now you can dynamically add new properties. It is more flexible in my opinion.